# Excel MATCH function returns #N/A when dividing lookup value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

A simple MATCH formula returns #N/A when, strangely, looking up 0.035*100 (= 3.5) in an array which contains 3, 3.5, 4 and 4.5.

[Error on 0.035*100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTMnm.png)

This correctly returns 4 when looking up 0.045*100. What's going on here?

Excel 365 version 2393

Expected 2 to be returned.

Comment: Lookup `ROUND(0.035*100, 1)`.

Comment: `=MATCH(ROUND(0.035*100, 15),A1:A4,0)`

Comment: OK, point taken. Why does =(0.035*100)=3.5 return TRUE though?